# How to create DOM tree from selector?

Tags: javascript, selector

How to create dynamically DOM elements (tree) from selector in JS?
Selector will be different in any other cases.

For example:

```
.first>.second>.third>ul>li
```

So in this case, I should get:

```
<div class="first">
    <div class="second">
        <div class="third">
            <ul>
                <li></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

After that I will be able to do 'appendChild' to body or some elements.

Comment: Are you asking for Emmet, or are you asking how to write an Emmet, or…?

Comment: And what about selectors that can have an infinite amount of possible DOM trees? For example `div div`

Comment: @josias Not sure what you mean. In the notation the OP is asking about that’d be `div>div` and would expand to nested divs. Doesn’t seem like an issue.

Comment: @DaveNewton OP is asking for a general solution. This is impossible because a selector can have N amount of different DOM structures. Even with a direct child selector you don't know how many children there are.
Sounds like an ill-defined problem

Comment: I need instead createElement('div.class'), to be able create DOM using simple selector for example: "createElement('.block>span.some')". I'm not talking about Emmet.

Comment: @josias There are as many children as contained in the input—it’s a direct conversion from input shorthand to output. It’s Emmet, which already exists.

Comment: Syntax the same as document.querySelector('.some_selector')

Comment: How many more times can I say Emmet before you realize it’s the answer.

Comment: Emmet - is this "ul>li*5", I don't need this syntax. I need syntax which can be available by 'document.querySelector' and Emmet support more than I need. For example: (div>dl>(dt+dd)*3)+footer>p

Comment: It doesn't matter if it has *more* than you need. It has what you ask for, and already exists. There's no magic by which `createElement(my_made_up_syntax)` will suddenly appear. You have to create it, and this is the easiest path to do so.